# Stata behaving totally differently depending on whether I put semicolon to comment

Tags: stata

If we put "*" in the beginning of the line then Stata is supposed to ignore the line.

But I find again and again that if I don't put semicolon at the end of the comment line, the program gives me spoiled estimation result.

Why is this?

Isn't Stata supposed to completely ignore the whole commented line?

Also, in general, when should I and shouldn't I put semicolon at the end of the line?

Comment: At a guess, you set `#delimit ;`. If so, then comment lines are lines too and need semi-colons as delimiters too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `;` at the end of a Stata command.

In both Stata and Mata this is entirely optional.

As you say, `*` is used for commenting, but this must be the first character 
of the line (excluding blanks) and it comments out only that line.

If you need multi-line comments or comments in the middle of some command, 
then use `/*` and `*/` (together).

The end of a command is established by a *delimiter*. The default delimiter
is a carriage return. You are able to change the delimiter to a `;` using `#delimit ;`
in your `.do` file or program; that doesn't work interactively. In this way, you can break
long commands into several lines without Stata complaining. The point is that 
you signal the end of the command explicitly using the `;`. But you need not
use `#delimit ;`. One way to break a long command into several lines is using `///` at the end of each line (except the last one).

All that said, you give no example code. You mention that Stata behaves totally
differently depending on semicolon (in your post title) but give no explanation
as to what this means.

Good readings may be `help semicolon`, `help delimit`, `help comments`.